# How can I optimise this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, join

I'm trying to make a filter which matches every record in the table to find ones which are within the range @min and @max. They're unxi timestamps if anyone was wondering.

It **does** work right now, but, without a doubt, it is *extremely* inefficient. I was wondering if anyone could spot any optimisations or improvements which could reduce the processing time/latency. Due to its nature (it's for reminders), I will be running the query every 2-3 seconds, which is all the more reason for it to be as efficient as possible :p

Thanks in advance

[This is the result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AxkT.png)

[The table's field types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU012.png)

```sql
SET @min := 1655827728037;
SET @max := 1656001256902;

SELECT * FROM (SELECT `user` FROM reminders
    WHERE @min < mission AND mission <= @max OR
          @min < report AND report <= @max OR
          @min < challenge AND challenge <= @max OR
          @min < tower AND tower <= @max OR
          @min < training AND training <= @max OR
          @min < daily AND daily <= @max OR
          @min < weekly AND weekly <= @max OR
          @min < quest AND quest <= @max OR
          @min < vote AND vote <= @max) AS users
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `user`, mission FROM reminders WHERE @min < mission AND mission <= @max) AS mission USING (`user`)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `user`, report FROM reminders WHERE @min < report AND report <= @max) AS report USING (`user`)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `user`, challenge FROM reminders WHERE @min < challenge AND challenge <= @max) AS challenge USING (`user`)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `user`, tower FROM reminders WHERE @min < tower AND tower <= @max) AS tower USING (`user`)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `user`, training FROM reminders WHERE @min < training AND training <= @max) AS training USING (`user`)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `user`, daily FROM reminders WHERE @min < daily AND daily <= @max) AS daily USING (`user`)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `user`, weekly FROM reminders WHERE @min < weekly AND weekly <= @max) AS weekly USING (`user`)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `user`, quest FROM reminders WHERE @min < quest AND quest <= @max) AS quest USING (`user`)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `user`, vote FROM reminders WHERE @min < vote AND vote <= @max) AS vote USING (`user`);
```

Comment: Your data storing schema is de-normalized which is obviously bad practice. I'd recommend to normalize it. *but, without a doubt, it is extremely inefficient* Pivotting is efficient never. Perform this transformation on the client side using its reporting service.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE reminders` to present the table.
- Use text, not images to provide information to us.
- Use a numeric datatype, perhaps `BIGINT` in your case, for a column that will be compared against numbers
- Perhaps have a single timestamp column, not one per type.
- Have one row per reminder, not clump them together

After you have done all those, come back for further critique.